# Horizontal UIScrollView set content offset does not work as content updates

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling

Implemented `UIScrollView` with scrolling in the horizontal direction only.
As the contents update, trying to set the content offset to max X position

```
let maxXOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.bounds.size.width, y: 0)
scrollView.setContentOffset(maxXOffset, animated: true)
```

but the issue is content offset not set correctly.

Comment: Hi, is there a question ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of your "content update" code, you are probably trying to get the `.contentSize` *before* it is ready.

Take a look at this example. It creates a scroll view containing a `UIStackView`. We start with 3 labels in the stack view. With each tap, we add a label, and then scroll to the end with `.setContentOffset(...)`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        stackView.spacing = 8
        
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        // start with 3 cyan labels in the stack view
        for i in 1...3 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.text = "Label \(i)"
            v.backgroundColor = .cyan
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let clg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 80.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 80.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -80.0),
            scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
            
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: clg.topAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: clg.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: clg.trailingAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: clg.bottomAnchor),
            
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.heightAnchor),
        ])
        
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gotTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(t)

    }
    
    @objc func gotTap(_ g: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        
        // add a green label to the stack view on every tap
        let v = UILabel()
        v.text = "Label \(stackView.arrangedSubviews.count + 1)"
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)

        // scroll to max X offset... but do it AFTER auto-layout has
        //  finished adding the new label
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let sv = self.scrollView
            let maxXOffset = CGPoint(x: sv.contentSize.width - sv.bounds.size.width, y: 0)
            sv.setContentOffset(maxXOffset, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
}
```